# Reverse For loop; should be easy

Tags: swift, loops

This should be easy but i'm making it hard for myself!
I've created a reverse For loop to iterate through a set.
If there are ten numbers in the set, then I could just do this;

```
for d in (0..<10).reverse()  {

        print(d)

}
```

but I want to match against an Int then count backwards in the set like this;

If myInt = 7, then I want to append 7 to an array (which I can do) but also append; 6,5,4,3,2,1,9,8 to the array in that order.

appreciate the help!

Comment: Which kind of result you want ?

Comment: Basically, if myInt is 7 then the array will be 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9,8.

Comment: You could probably create a first array containing from `myInt` to 1 then a second array from `yourArraySize.count` (here it's 10) to your `myInt` then you concatenate both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you get your array like this :-

```
let myInt = 7
var outPutArray : NSMutableArray = []
var tempArray : NSMutableArray = []
for d in (0..<10)  {
    if myInt-d <= 0
    {
        if myInt-d != 0
        {
            tempArray.addObject(d)
        }

    }else{
        outPutArray.addObject(myInt-d)
    }

}
outPutArray.addObjectsFromArray(tempArray.reverse())

print(outPutArray)
```

> 7,
>       6,
>       5,
>       4,
>       3,
>       2,
>       1,
>       8,
>       9

Comment: i get (from the above);  outArray = (
    2,
    1,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9
) when myInt = 2

Comment: This is the right. Dynamic any value se on myInt then you get as per your requirements.

Comment: Suppose myInt - 2 then what kind of output ?

Comment: Yes, just need the whole array descending; so as per your output; 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 9 but 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8

Comment: Give me some examples supposed myint -4 or 6 then output ?

Comment: I just completed when you posted but I did it creating two arrays of Int and sorting then combining them from your original answer but your answer is better! thanks very much - i'll up vote you!

Comment: Why would you use `NSMutableArray` here?

Comment: This is just logic we also use NSArray also.

Comment: @mitulmarsonia: you should use the Swift native Array struct instead of the `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray` classes.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to split the range at `myInt` and use two separate iterations. I would probably use this:

```
let range: Range<Int> = 0..<10
let pivot: Int = 7

let result = Array(range.startIndex...pivot).reverse()
    + Array(pivot.successor()..<range.endIndex).reverse() // or "pivot + 1"
print(result) // [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8]
```

If you don't want the `0` there, just drop it from the input `range` (`1..<10`). Don't create an additional condition for it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Sulthan's answer, this one uses `stride` to construct the array:

**Swift 2.x:**

```
let (start, end) = (1, 9)
let pivot = 7

let result = Array(pivot.stride(through: start, by: -1)) +
    Array(end.stride(to: pivot, by: -1))
print(result)
```

Output:

> ```
> [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8]
> ```

---

**Swift 3:**

```
let result = Array(stride(from: pivot, through: start, by: -1)) +
    Array(stride(from: end, to: pivot, by: -1))
```